# Secure copy scp or rsync with wildcard on multiple folders with similar subfolders/subtrees

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, centos, redhat

Hi i need help to be able to complete the following attempt -- backup the codes and notebooks I have developed in remote machine thus far onto my local machine. I believe many have similar thoughts to backups work regularly.

I have multiple folders with similar subfolders that i only want to copy the subfolders.

Eg. at the remote machine

```
/home/userme/Project1/Codes/Python_scripts/    
/home/userme/Project1/Codes/R_scripts/    
/home/userme/Project2/Codes/Python_scripts/    
/home/userme/Project2/Codes/R_scripts/    
/home/userme/Project3/Codes/Python_scripts/    
/home/userme/Project3/Codes/R_scripts/    
....
```

Please note that the Project* folders may contain large inputs or output folders/files that i don't want to back up. I only want the specific Codes folder to be cp'ed/scp'ed.

I thought of doing the following but i am sure it won't work with this:

```
$ scp -rf userme@10.128.1.1:/home/userme/*/Codes .
```

I need quick bash script template or 1-liner that you may already have it, please help ;)

Comment: Why not `for i in /home/userme/Project*; do scp -rf "$i/Codes" userme@10.128.1.1:"$i"; done` (and personally I would use `rsync` instead of `scp`...)

Comment: Yes please suggest a rsync solution if you have one. I have changed the title to scp or rsync now

Comment: With `rsync` you have the `**` wildcard available, but that doesn't help at the `Project**` level, because you don't have a guarantee that `ProjectX` will already be present on the remote host. So with `rsync` I would still do the same thing, but use `-au` as the option instead of `-rf`. If you structure your `Project` (no `X`) directory so all the code is below that one directory, that would make backup trivial with either `scp` or `rsync` (e.g `/home/userme/Projects/Project{1,2,3,...}`)